# What if a Goel HaDam (Blood Redeemer) accidentally kills his kinsman's accidental murderer - inside the latter's 'Ir Miklat (City of Refuge)?

Tags: halacha, mistakes, murder, city-of-refuge

[Another question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26793/5) asks what happens if someone accidentally kills someone else inside an 'Ir Miklat (City of Refuge) in which the victim and/or his family live, and whether he needs to move to another City of Refuge to be safe from the Goel HaDam (Blood Redeemer).

But what happens if an accidental murderer is living as a refugee in a City of Refuge, which happens to be visited by the Goel HaDam for whatever reason, who accidentally kills the refugee?

Does the former Goel have to seek refuge for an accidental murder? Can he seek refuge in place (the city in which he committed the accidental murder, which *would* be exile because he was merely visiting there)?

Comment: Accidentally because he didn't mean to kill him, or accidentally because he didn't know he wasn't allowed to in that place?

Comment: @HodofHod, didn't mean to.

Comment: ...and they were both wearing Shaatnez on Yom Kippur while chewing gum and dragging a plow...

Comment: @double but they didn't realize it was Yom Kippur.

Comment: I'm sure we could assume he would not get galus being that as a goel hadam he would be assumed to harbor feelings of animosity and his killing of him would be considered karov limeizid.

Comment: @user6591 why do you assume that. Can't there be Goel Hadam's who arenforgiving and wouldn't look to avenge the blood of their relatives. Compare to a car accident killing a person, some family members can forgive the person responsible.

Comment: @Yoreinu Anything is possible. But we only rule based on what we see and can assume. Just like if someone hadn't spoken to a fellow for three days and accidentally kills him we say it's karov limeizid, so too in situation.

Comment: @user6591 even if he spoke to him within the past 3 days? Any source?